# Pig HBASE Ingestion from HDFS error: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, apache-pig, bigdata

During Pig HBASE Ingestion from HDFS I am getting `Unhandled internal error`. `Bad type on operand stack as exception` while running pig as MR mode.

```
2017-03-08 04:02:57,329 [main] ERROR
org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
   - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Bad type on operand stack Exception Details:   Location:   
org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.initScan()V @320:
invokespecial   Reason:    Type
'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/BinaryComparator' (current frame,
stack[6]) is not assignable to   
'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ByteArrayComparable'   Current
Frame:    bci: @320    flags: { }    locals: {
'org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage', '[B' }    stack:
{ 'org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage', uninitialized
298, uninitialized 298, uninitialized 302,    uninitialized 302,   
'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/CompareFilter$CompareOp',   
'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/BinaryComparator' }
```

I am using pig 0.16.0 with Apache Hadoop 2.7 & Hbase 0.94.27.